# Decorating an AngularJS Directive

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, decorator

I've been following [this post](http://angular-tips.com/blog/2013/09/experiment-decorating-directives/) in order to augment or change [UI Bootstrap](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap). It's been very useful, but I've recently hit a snag while augmenting the [datepicker](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/datepicker). I've got the following (trimmed) decorator:

```js
DatepickerDecorator.$inject = ['$delegate', '$compile', 'shWrapper'];
function DatepickerDecorator($delegate, $compile, shWrapper) {
    var directive = $delegate[0],
        controller = directive.controller;

    directive.controller = myDatepickerController;

    myDatepickerController.$inject = ['$scope', '$element', '$attrs', '$controller'];
    function myDatepickerController($scope, $element, $attrs, $controller) {
        angular.extend(this, $controller(controller, {
            $scope: $scope,
            $element: $element,
            $attrs: $attrs
        }));
    }

    return $delegate;
}
```

For some reason this breaks the datepicker. The user can no longer navigate between months in the `day` mode.

Why is this breaking the functionality and how can I fix it?

---

Here's a snippet replicating the issue:

```js
var module = angular.module('decorate.datepicker', ['ui.bootstrap']);
module.config(ConfigureDatepicker);

ConfigureDatepicker.$inject = ['$provide'];
function ConfigureDatepicker($provide) {
  // Augment Angular Bootstrap's datepicker (popup)
  $provide.decorator('uibDatepickerDirective', DatepickerDecorator);
}

DatepickerDecorator.$inject = ['$delegate'];
function DatepickerDecorator($delegate) {
  var directive = $delegate[0],
    controller = directive.controller;

  // You can comment out this line and it will work.
  directive.controller = myDatepickerController;

  myDatepickerController.$inject = ['$scope', '$element', '$attrs', '$controller'];
  function myDatepickerController($scope, $element, $attrs, $controller) {
    angular.extend(this, $controller(controller, {
      $scope: $scope,
      $element: $element,
      $attrs: $attrs
    }));
  }

  return $delegate;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/1.2.1/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div ng-app="decorate.datepicker">
    <p>Once the input or datepicker has focus, ESC closes the datepicker and the down arrow opens it.</p>
    <input ng-model="dt" uib-datepicker-popup />
  </div>
</body>
```

The exception it throws is:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'years' of undefined
>       
>     at r.$scope.move (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/1.2.1/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js:2206:70)
>       
>     at fn (eval at  (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js:213:110), :4:227)
>       
>     at e (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js:254:74)
>       
>     at r.$eval (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js:133:313)
>       
>     at r.$apply (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js:134:17)
>       
>     at HTMLButtonElement. (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js:254:126)
>       
>     at If (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js:35:367)
>       
>     at HTMLButtonElement.Hf.d (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js:35:314)

In `day` mode, the step variable is defined on line 2160 in https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/1.2.1/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js.

Comment: I was able to resolve this by moving all the logic to a link override instead of a controller override and utilizing the controllers parameter. I'm nonetheless curious to know the answer. It's a bit disconcerting to think some of my other controller overrides might be inadvertently breaking existing functionality.